# Function to count how many values in an array complement with a given key

Tags: c++, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I tried doing an algorithm that will count how many elements in a matrix complement their last **S** bits with the same last **S** number of bits of a given key.

Let's assume S equals 3, the number that is to be verified is 12 and the key is 3.
In binary representation 12 = (00001100) and 3 = (00000011). If we apply xor to these two values we obtain 15 (00001111). But we only take into account the last S (3) bits and because they are all equal to 1 the numbers are complemented.
If we were to have the same number 12 but the key 5 (00000101), the result of xor would return 9 (00001001), but the last S (3) bits are not all 1's, so it is not complemented.

I tried implementing the algorithm for this in c++, and although I went over it again and again, I cannot seem to find a logical error in it. I ask you because this code is used in a problem that I work on and the website that automatically  evaluates it does not grant it all the points that this subproblem would obtain.

```
int complement()
{
    //map is a globally declared matrix
    //k is the key, also global
    //S is the number of bits we take into account, also global
    int i, j, nr=0, mask, aux;
    mask = (1<<S)-1;
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
        for(j=1; j<=m; j++)
        {
            aux = map[i][j]^k;
            if( aux & mask == mask)
            {
                map[i][j]=0;    //overwritten as 0 meaning it is good
                nr++;
            }
            else map[i][j]=-1;  //overwritten as -1
        }
    return nr;     //how many numbers could be complemented
}

For the matrix:
15 1278 3  1278 1278 1 
16 17   18 19   254  20
21 25   26 254  254  254
27 28   29 3    2    254
2  254  4  254  254  254

The program returns:
-1  0 -1  0 0 -1 
 0 -1  0 -1 0  0 
-1 -1  0  0 0  0 
-1  0 -1 -1 0  0 
 0  0  0  0 0  0 

and nr = 20.
```

Restrictions:

- S <= 8
- all values and the key <= 9999

Comment: You should use unsigned variables and literals if you're going to be shifting them.

Comment: Off-by-one error? Shouldn't you iterate `for(i=0; i<n; i++)` instead of `for(i=1; i<=n; i++)`, and the same for `j`?

Comment: Get rid of the global variables (at least pass them as function arguments) and write a test case showing the problem

Comment: The numbers are stored with an offset of 1 in both dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C/C++ operator precedence for bitwise operation is "buggy".

In C/C++

```
aux & mask == mask
```

is parsed as

```
aux & (mask == mask)
```

You need to write instead

```
(aux & mask) == mask
```

because otherwise `aux` will end up and-ed with 1 every time independently of mask size.

Comment: Thanks! I just changed that and the whole program containing this got 10/10.